# Receive Java Socket in PHP

Tags: php, android, sockets

I've got the following problem:

I just created a new Socket connection and told my mediaRecorder to send its recorded data via socket:

```
Socket soc=null;
try {
    soc = new Socket("192.168.178.103",8888);
    Log.i(TAG, "Connected to socket");
} catch (Exception e) {
}

ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = ParcelFileDescriptor.fromSocket(soc);
myCamera = getCameraInstance();
mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

myCamera.unlock();
mediaRecorder.setCamera(myCamera);

mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);

mediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_LOW));

mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(pfd.getFileDescriptor());
.
.
.
```

I have the following php test code from http://www.binarytides.com/udp-socket-programming-in-php/:

```
<?php

//Reduce errors
error_reporting(~E_WARNING);

//Create a UDP socket
if(!($sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)))
{
    $errorcode = socket_last_error();
    $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

    die("Couldn't create socket: [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
}

echo "Socket created \n";

// Bind the source address
if( !socket_bind($sock, "192.168.178.103" , 8888) )
{
    $errorcode = socket_last_error();
    $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

    die("Could not bind socket : [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
}

echo "Socket bind OK \n";

//Do some communication, this loop can handle multiple clients
while(1)
{
    echo "Waiting for data ... \n";

    //Receive some data
    $r = socket_recvfrom($sock, $buf, 512, 0, $remote_ip, $remote_port);
    echo "$remote_ip : $remote_port -- " . $buf;

    //Send back the data to the client
    socket_sendto($sock, "OK " . $buf , 100 , 0 , $remote_ip , $remote_port);
}

socket_close($sock);
```

I just tested around when i just write something like "procedured" in a file when my index.php on the server side is called. It works, but with this code my socket does not receive any data.
Do you have a clue for me?
Thank you!

Comment: Can you show the code where you tell your mediaRecorder to send recorded data via socket?

Comment: @greenapps Uhm damn, I have checked some tutorials on the net where they just do it like this:mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(pfd.getFileDescriptor());
is there any other stuff needed? Thank you for your reply :)

Comment: That does not answer my question. Look at the code you posted. You create `soc`. Now where did you tell your mediaRecorder to use it? Something is missing. Everybody can see that.

Comment: Sorry, just forgot one crucial line... Just added it right below the catch-block @greenapps

Comment: Please show in another code block how you did that with writing something in a file.